# Difference between Google Cloud's INTERNAL ephemeral and static IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#networkaddresses

I understand that for 'external'(public) IP address, 'ephemeral' means IP address changes on next start/stop of the VM whereas 'static' setting causes the IP to be reserved.

However, a bit confused on 'internal' IP address as the above document refers to IP being attached to VM even on next start/stop cycle for both 'ephemeral' and 'static'. So what is the difference between the 2 settings when talking about internal IP addresses?

Kind regards.
Aditya

Answer (score 5):

Here is the difference:

**Static internal IP addresses**: these addresses are assigned to a project long term until they are explicitly released from that assignment, and remain attached to a resource until they are explicitly detached from the resource.

For VM instances, static internal IP addresses remain attached to stopped instances until they are removed.

**Ephemeral internal IP addresses**: these addresses are available to VM instances and forwarding rules. Ephemeral internal IP addresses remain attached to VM instances and forwarding rules until the instance or forwarding rule is deleted.

You can assign an ephemeral internal IP address when you create a resource by omitting an IP address specification in your request and letting Compute Engine randomly assign an address.

Comment: Sometime you need to use static IP (internal or external) to allow only it to access to other system/network (especially legacy systems)